# Espresso with mock location : avoid Google's experience popup

Tags: mocking, google-play-services, android-espresso, gcloud, firebase-test-lab

I'm working on some UI testing with Espresso on a map based application that use the user location.

### Setup

- MapBox is used for the map component, no Google Map component used here.
- Google Play services libraries are used for localization purposes
- Tests using Espresso
- Mock used to fake the location (can be found here: [How to write Espresso Tests which are mocking GPS locations and use them in Google Testlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52440243/10472007))
- Tests run remotely on Firebase test Lab on a virtual device.

### Actual results / Problem

It works: the user location is then faked to the lat long I coded. But after a while I get some trouble. After few tests I get a system popup that seems to be triggered by `com.google.android.gms:play-services` that is embbeded in our application.

The message is "For a better experience, turn on device location, which uses Google's location service." as you can see on the picture below :

[image: Google location service popup]

So it seems that the mocking code trigger somehow this popup and then ruins all the remaining tests since the popup does not dismiss until clicked on one of the buttons.

### UI Automator: not a proper solution

I know I could add a bit of code with UI Automator in order to validate the popup but I would like to avoid this workaround since:

- I don't know what trigger this popup (seems random)
- I don't want to run some crappy/duplicated code before running each test just for that popup.
- Actually I am not using UI Atomator for my tests and I don't want to import another library to my project.

Please note that I cannot reproduce this problem on my device or my emulator but only when I run my tests on gcloud (Firebase Test Lab)...

### Question

Have you ever faced this problem ? Do you have any idea how I can avoid this popup or any workaround that is not involving UI Automator?

### One More Thing

Please remember that i'm running tests remotely, on a virtual device that is not logged into any Google Account. Also, I don't have access to the device system/settings but eventually I should be able to use ADB command to get some rights or apply some settings to the system.

---

### Bad news

Actually the mock location is partially supported on Firebase Test Lab on virtual devices. See my comment below for more information.

So depending the use case, switching to a real device can solve your problem like the problem mentionned in this topic.

Comment: I was also having this issue but without Firebase Test Lab. Instead, my automated tests run on my Jenkins server. Instead of using a Google Play or Google APIs image, I was able to use the basic x86 image, which never presents the popup.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you are seeing may be a bug in Firebase Test Lab if it is happening on certain devices but works on others. E.g. works on a physical Samsung device but does not work on a physical HTC device. Or works on all physical devices but does not work on virtual devices.

Since I cannot message you directly on Stack Overflow, I encourage you to join the Firebase Test Lab Slack channel (#test-lab) on https://firebase-community.slack.com/.

There will be Firebase engineers actively investigating issues that you are seeing and look directly at the test runs you have run in your project.

Comment: You're right ! I just got some feedback from the community and it seems that virtual devices on FTL does not support mock location, or partially since you can grant your application to be a mocking app but it has a weird behaviour like the problem in this thread or the position going back to the virtual device first position despite the mock... I'm going to update this thread.

Comment: this answer is not helpful, at all neither is this thread :( , @MrAurelien could you atleast post the UIAutomator solution for this?