# Access to the virtual device’s location on Firebase Test Lab

Tags: firebase, android-espresso, firebase-test-lab

I'm running Espresso Android tests on a virtual device (Pixel2) of Firebase Test Lab and I need to know the geographic coordinates of this device. I have tests that fail because they must run on a device located in national territory (Portugal) and it's displayed the following: “Your access is being made outside Portugal".
I would like to know if when I run the test via the command `gcloud firebase test android run`, there is a way to get access to the virtual device's location and / or to make it run on a device located in national territory (Portugal).

Thanks,
xptoGirl

Comment: Try a web search for "firebase test lab mock gps location".

Answer (score 2):

The default GPS location for virtual devices is (37.779564,-122.391616) (as of November 2019). This spot is inside San Francisco, California. Note that you cannot change this location.

For physical devices you might not get a GPS location at all, or it can be anywhere in the world.

Your best bet is to mock the GPS location, e.g. take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52440243/how-to-write-espresso-tests-which-are-mocking-gps-locations-and-use-them-in-goog).

Comment: Thanks! Strange that this answer wasn't accepted.